# Не могу отправить данные из базы в бота в телеграме

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Делаю бота для телеграм при помощи библиотеки Telegram Bot SDK, использую вебхук. На обычную отправку сообщений бот отвечает, как задумано, а вот данные из базы почему-не видит. Сейчас покажу пример на коде:

// Database. php

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
        return $this->pdo;
    }

    public function getOne()
    {
        $this->statement = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT content FROM problems WHERE id=2 LIMIT 1");
        $this->statement->execute();
        return $this->statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); Вот тут я возвращаю нужные мне данные

    }
```

// Telegram.php

```
    public function sendMessage(array $params)
    {
        return $this->bot->sendMessage($params);
    }
```

// new_bot.php

```
$bot = new Telegram($data['api']);
$db  = new Database();
$message = $db->getOne()->content; // вот тут приходит строка (она точно приходит, я проверял)
$text    = $bot->Get_Text();
$chat_id = $bot->Chat_Id();


switch ($text) {
    case "/start":
        $bot->sendMessage([
            'chat_id' => $chat_id,
            'text' => "Что надо?"
        ]);
        break;
    case "/help":
        $bot->sendMessage([
            'chat_id' => $chat_id,
            'text' => "Я вам ничем не помогу, спасайтесь сами."
        ]);
        break;
    case "/file":
        $bot->sendDocument([
            'chat_id' => $chat_id
        ]);
        break;
    case "/problem":
        $bot->sendMessage([
            'chat_id' => $chat_id,
            'text' => $message
        ]);
        break;
    default:
        $bot->sendMessage([
            'chat_id' => $chat_id,
            'text' => "Это ещё что? Я не понимаю."
        ]);
        break;
}
```

Так вот, в case "/problem" метод sendMessage не хочет отправлять данные. Кодировка верная, данные из базы приходят (проверял). Что может быть не так?

Comment: проверьте, действительно ли передается chat_id, и текст самого сообщения пропускайте через htmlspecialchars() потому что на некоторые символы или теги, телеграм выдает ошибку, нужно заменить html сущностями, ну и для отладки лучше смотреть еще ответ сервера Телеграм, сервер присылает код ошибки и ее описание, при отправке запроса, а там уже точно будет ясно в чем ваша проблема.

Comment: @Денис, да, всё передаётся. сейчас проверил, выполнив другой запрос, но уже к таблице users, откуда взял поле username, значение которого на латинице, так вот оно передалось нормально - я получил его в боте. а вот значения на кириллице не передаются. возможно, проблема с кодировкой, но везде, где только возможно, я указал utf8mb4, к тому же когда делаю дамп значения $db->getOne()->content получаю  нужное мне поле в нормальном виде.

Comment: а я понял, вы используете username для отправки сообщений? вообще не стоит его где то использовать, как ID нужно использовать именно chat id или from id потому что в Телеграм username может не быть вообще, обязательный параметр только first_name. И он может быть и на кириллице и специальными символами, что не позволит отправлять сообщения, поэтому стоит использовать только chat id набор цифр, это значение дается при регистрации и не меняется.

Comment: @Денис, нет, я лишь проверял, отправляется латиница или нет, потому что в chat_id интовые значения, которые точно отправляются, а в username - латиница. на самом деле, я отправляю сообщения по chat_id, а не username. кстати, я решил проблему -- надо было лишь поменять хостера, где нет проблем с кодировкой. теперь всё отправляется нормально.

Answer (score 0):

Я решил проблему и оставлю этот ответ на будущее тем, у кого будет такая же проблема. Всё дело было в кодировке, телеграм очень чувствителен к ней. Так что если у вас ничего не получается, меняйте хостера. Я поменял и всё заработало.